# Android: Separate intents for email & SMS

Tags: android

I have an app that has two buttons – one for email & one for SMS. Depending on the button pressed I want to email or else SMS a certain text. I have coded the email button and it is working fine. The problem is that the dialog box that pops-up gives an option of e-mail or Messaging the text. I want to separate out the two, so that when the user presses email, only the options of email is there, and when the user presses SMS, only the option of Messaging is there.

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
private void sendEmail(){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    i.setType("text/plain"); 
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"}); 
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject of the message"); 
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Body of the message"); 
    try { 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...")); 
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) { 
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
}
```

Basically there seems to be a single intent  Intent.ACTION_SEND for both emails & Messaging.

Any way to separate them out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can launch the Messaging application with a prepopulated message like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

or do something like this to just send it straightaway, without presenting the Messaging app:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");   
startActivity(it);
```

Comment: I used the first one (since I wanted to launch the SMS app to give the user chance to edit the text). It works great! Just as you use "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" for setType for SMS, do you happen to know the String to use for sending email only?

Answer (score -3):

String to use for sending email only is:

```
email.setType("message/rfc822");
```