# "Tell a Friend" example (sending email/SMS to people in contacts)

Tags: android

I'm developing application where I need to add the functionality of allowing user to send either email or SMS to people in his contact book about app.

Thus, I wonder if somebody wrote such code and would like to share it, or if you know any example in Internet where could I use.

or at least, if you know any example of sending SMS or email it will be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question: [Android: Separate intents for email & SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3136991/1267661) shows you how to send information via email and sms.

You should also read the Developer Guides where they discuss the [ShareActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). The ShareActionProvider allows you to easily transfer information from your app to another (like Facebook, Twitter, or any app that is ready).